# Disable auto log in with Facebook loginbutton

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have an Android application that uses Facebook sdk to log in. To do so, I use the LoginButton widget. The log in process works very well but I got a small problem : when I close the application or reinstall it, it automatically logs in into Facebook (the text on button switches to "Log out"). I don't want to have such behavior : I need that the user clicks on the button to log in every time the application starts. I checked on the internet and it seems this feature is called "single sign on" but I'm not sure about that. I have found several ways to do so but none of them works. I used Facebook SDK 4. This is the part of the code that instantiates the Activity.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
this.setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

getSupportActionBar().hide();

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

/*accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
        updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
    }
};*/

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogInActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_birthday", "email"));
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
fb_login = ((LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login));
fb_login.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);

fb_login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.i("Facebook connect", "Connection success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.i("Facebook", "Super c'et cancel");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.account)).setText("Annulé");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.i("Facebook", "Super y a une erreur");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.account)).setText("Erreur");
    }
});
```

Does someone have an idea how to disable to automatic connection ?

Comment: What have you tried? have you tried calling Logout() on the login manager? or maybe calling this and see if it helps [`AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/001984c85bbb5ccb7a3df4e33fe3090d22a8ac88/samples/SwitchUserSample/src/com/example/switchuser/SettingsFragment.java)

Answer (score 4):

For Facebook SDK 4 and onwards, you could programmatically logout using:

`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

Now, the problem is where do you place this code. If you're fine with Facebook logout when the app is sent to the background, you can use `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods.

The big part comes. You can't determine if the app is killed. Because it's simply killed and you don't get any callbacks to catch that event.

So, if you anyway want to implement this every-time-login thing, you have to do this when the app starts.

1. Initialize the Facebook SDK:
2. Check if the user is logged in.
3. If yes in step 2, run manual logout.

   ```
   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
   if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
       LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
   }
   ```

Comment: The sdkInitialize is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

step 1: like was written before you should make

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

step 2: To remove autologin just avoid behavior of Facebook app. You could do it via LoginBehavior.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogInActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_birthday", "email"));
```